# "Invalid Escape Sequence" with regex in Haxe

Tags: regex, haxe

How can I get Haxe to match parentheses in regular expressions?

I always get the error `Invalid Escape Sequence`.

```
var reg = new EReg('\([0-9]+\)', 'i'); // Throws error
reg.match('(9)');
trace(reg.matched(0));
```

http://try.haxe.org/#345D6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In strings, you need to escape the `\` character using `\\`. The following works:

```
var reg = new EReg('\\([0-9]+\\)', 'i');
```

Alternatively, Haxe has [regex literals](http://haxe.org/manual/std-regex.html) you can use here:

```
var reg = ~/\([0-9]+\)/i;
```